# Custom notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications

How to get Popup notifications?

As i have observed all the notifications are added in the status bar, but i want the notifications in popup, how can i do that?

I also want to add speech to text feature for the notifications. Please someone help me, if u have idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Custom dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)